# Problem with redirect the url with always last slash

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with redirect a url always with the last slash. I use this code in my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?control_pages=$1
```

Later in php, **I capture the route** to work it in my script with de **explode() function**.

But I try to always redirect with htaccess my urls, for example to:

web.com/news/this-is-a-new **--> TO -->** web.com/news/this-is-a-new/

I tried with much examples from internet but none work it me..

I appreciate any little help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but it reads as if you *want* a trailing slash in your `control_pages` argument for your php based logic to work correctly.

If so you actually need to add that slash while rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ index.php?control_pages=$1/ [END,B]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).